# How to make synchronized movement of Bottom sheet dialog fragment and keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to make bottom sheet dialog and keyboard synchronized movement in android, kotlin. I start bottom sheet dialog fragment from another fragment by navController:

```
 private fun listeners(){
        binding.btnBottomSheetDialog.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionBlankFragmentToBottomSheetDialogFragment())
        }
    }
```

it's layout of bottom sheet dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.bottom_sheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:hint="Enter your name" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bottom sheet dialog fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="random text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/input"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/input"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it's dialog fragment code:

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.example.keyboardevent.R
import com.example.keyboardevent.databinding.FragmentBottomSheetDialogBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment

class BottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentBottomSheetDialogBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding.input.requestFocus()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentBottomSheetDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val bottomSheetDialog =
            super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        bottomSheetDialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        if (bottomSheetDialog is BottomSheetDialog) {
            bottomSheetDialog.behavior.skipCollapsed = true
            bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
        return bottomSheetDialog
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

My navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/blankFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment"
        android:name="com.example.keyboardevent.fragments.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_blank"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_blankFragment_to_bottomSheetDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottomSheetDialogFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.keyboardevent.fragments.bottom_sheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment"
        android:label="BottomSheetDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog"/>
</navigation>
```

This's bottom sheet style:

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
    </style>
```

I wrote this in manifest also for activity:

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

bottom sheet fragment moves up firstly and after that keyboard moves up. I want they move at the same time.

I try to use WindowInsetsAnimationCompat Callback for keyboard animation but it was working only for fragment's views and keyboard, not for dialog fragment and keyboard.

How can I make animation that moves bottom sheet dialog up to keyboard with synchronized movement? or is there other way?

[image: it's homeFragment screen:]

[image: it's bottom sheet dialog fragment screen]